# Ansible: How to use backslash in lineinfile module?

Tags: ansible, backslash

```
---
- hosts: local

  tasks:
  - name: Update cataline.properties 1
    lineinfile:  dest=/home/folder1/catalina.properties insertafter="# been granted." line="package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,\"
```

> ERROR! Unexpected Exception: zero length field name in format

Answer (score 0):

---

- hosts: local

  tasks:

  - name: Update cataline.properties 1
    lineinfile:  dest=/home/folder1/catalina.properties insertafter="# been granted." line="package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,\ "

If I am ending the line with \ and a space, then close with ", It works but in line replacement, it will add space as well.